# How can I diagnose and remedy strange download behavior from an Azure public blob?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I host a software product on Azure, and store the downloads themselves in a public container, which the website links to via URL.  You can see my downloads page here:  https://flyinside-fsx.com/Download

Normally I get somewhere in the range of 200mb-500mb worth of downloads per day, with the downloaded files themselves being 15-30mb.  Starting these week, I've seen spikes of up to 220GB per day from this storage container.  It hasn't harmed the website in any way but the transfer is costing me money.  I'm certainly not seeing an increase in website traffic that would accompany 220GB worth of downloads, so this appears to either be some sort of DOS attack or a broken automated downloader.

Is there a way to remedy this situation?  Can I set the container to detect and block malicious traffic?  Or should I be using a different type of file hosting entirely, which offers these sorts of protections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's going on with your storage account, best way would be to use [`Storage Analytics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343270.aspx) especially see the [`storage activity logs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343259.aspx). These logs are stored in a special blob container called `$logs`. You can download the contents of the blob using any storage explorer which supports exploring the contents of it.

I would highly recommend starting from there and identify what exactly is going on. Based on the findings, you can take some corrective actions. For example, if the traffic is coming via some bots, you can put a simple CAPTCHA on the download page.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was able to track down the source, a single IP address in China downloading one of my files over and over.  I don't think a CAPTCHA will help, as they are directly hitting the blob URL.  Any suggestions on restricting this traffic?

Comment: Blobs are just an HTTP endpoint.  So standard tools could be used.  Azure doesn't have anything built-in unless you restrict it from being public and then grant SAS tokens everytime you want someone to download the file.  Probably a better way to go anyways, that way your app can control who has access (by providing or not providing the SAS token)

Comment: @CtrlDot +1 for SAS. I checked the website and currently there's direct access to blob so anybody could copy the download URL. What can be done instead is to create short-lived SAS on the files to be downloaded and use SAS URL instead. But first, I would recommend changing the download URL (move files from one container to another) so that if someone is using the direct link, at least they will not be able to download files over and over. However it is highly recommended to switch to SAS URL ASAP.